# Node.js - Could not locate the bindings file

Tags: node.js, windows-7, node-ffi

I'm trying to run an app of node-ffi on my windows 7 PC with Nodejs v6.2.0, but it crashes with the following error . I tried a variety of methods, but did not resolve my problem

```
   E:\iwork\workbase\myapp\node_modules\bindings\bindings.js:91 Uncaught Error: Could not locate the bindings file. Tried:
 → E:\iwork\workbase\myapp\node_modules\ref\build\binding.node
 → E:\iwork\workbase\myapp\node_modules\ref\build\Debug\binding.node
 → E:\iwork\workbase\myapp\node_modules\ref\build\Release\binding.node
 → E:\iwork\workbase\myapp\node_modules\ref\out\Debug\binding.node
 → E:\iwork\workbase\myapp\node_modules\ref\Debug\binding.node
 → E:\iwork\workbase\myapp\node_modules\ref\out\Release\binding.node
 → E:\iwork\workbase\myapp\node_modules\ref\Release\binding.node
 → E:\iwork\workbase\myapp\node_modules\ref\build\default\binding.node
 → E:\iwork\workbase\myapp\node_modules\ref\compiled\6.1.0\win32\ia32\binding.node
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to install module:

```
npm install bindings --save
npm install
```

re launch app.

More info at https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-bindings

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue. For me, downgrading the node version from 7.3.0 to 6.9.2 worked. I am not sure what is the exact reason though.